# Error trying to pre-select an option in a DropDownList within EditItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, edit

Why am I getting a Runtime error when trying to pre-select a value from a DropDownList in ASP.net 2.0 vb?

I've tried to do the same thing with a GridView and I get the same message.

Initially I'm trying to show the user the details they submitted to apply for access.  When clicking the edit button, I want to allow the user to alter the details they submitted to us and update the application.  I'm not looking to do any additional inserting into the database.

I wanted to restrict the user to selecting the department from a DropDownList.  When the user clicks edit, I want the department they originally applied with to be pre-selected.  When I have the line:

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("department") %>'
```

I get a Runtime error.  If I remove the line, it doesn't error but doesn't pre-select anything.

Is anyone able to help me understand why its not working?

Something else that might help is that I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and as I type class properties are being shown as I type.  I can see lots of properties for the DropDownList when I press my spacebar, but SelectedValue isn't one of them which makes me think I'm  trying to do something which isn't supposed to work.

My Code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="UserDetails_Conn" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NormCon %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email, d.department FROM mis_userlist AS u INNER JOIN mis_depts AS d ON u.dept_id = d.dept_id WHERE (u.windows_login = @windows_ID)"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE mis_userlist SET first_name = @first_name, last_name = @last_name, email = @email, dept_id = @dept_id WHERE (windows_login = @windows_ID)"
>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="windows_ID" SessionField="username" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="first_name" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="last_name" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="email" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="dept_id" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="windows_ID" />
    </UpdateParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DetailsView ID="UserDetailsView" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="UserDetails_Conn">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="first_name" HeaderText="first_name" SortExpression="first_name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="last_name" HeaderText="last_name" SortExpression="last_name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="email" SortExpression="email" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="department" SortExpression="department">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DepartmentList" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NormCon %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT dept_id, department FROM mis_depts ORDER BY department"
                >
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartments" runat="server"
                    DataSourceId="DepartmentList"
                    DataTextField="department"
                    DataValueField="dept_id"
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("department") %>' > <!-- Errorsome line -->
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("department") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("department") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

### **Solution**

Along with Win's Solution, I needed to add the dept_id field in the SQL string.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email, d.department, d.dept_id FROM mis_userlist AS u INNER JOIN mis_depts AS d ON u.dept_id = d.dept_id WHERE (u.windows_login = @windows_ID)"
```

This allowed department when represented here: 
    ddlDepartments.SelectedValue = department
to be a value that could link with my DataValueField="dept_id" line from the DropDownList.

Thanks to Win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectedValue` will throw an exception if you assign a value which doesn't exists in the list.

In order to avoid that, you can validate in [DataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.dataitem.aspx) -

Remove `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("department") %>'` from aspx page, and attach data bound event to UserDetailsView `<asp:DetailsView ... OnDataBound="DetailsView_DataBound" ...`

```
Protected Sub DetailsView_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   Dim detailsView = DirectCast(sender, DetailsView)

   Dim dr = DirectCast(detailsView.DataItem, DataRowView)
   Dim department = dr(4).ToString() ' Column index of department
   *** OR *** Dim department = dr("department").ToString() ' Column by name
   Dim ddlDepartments = TryCast(detailsView.
      FindControl("ddlDepartments"), DropDownList)

   If ddlDepartments IsNot Nothing AndAlso 
      ddlDepartments.Items.FindByValue(department) IsNot Nothing Then
      ddlDepartments.SelectedValue = department
   End If
End Sub
```

Basically, you are intercepting data binding of controls.

**Updated**: checking the index of department column.
[image]

Comment: Thanks again,  I tried looking into understanding the code and added it to my webpage.  Its giving me a Runtime error.  If I take out the OnDataBound="..." bit it works how it did before.  Am I missing something obvious as this seems like it shouldn't be this hard right?

Comment: Make the break point at 'Dim department = dr(4).ToString()' and check the column index of department. Then enter the index inside dr(xxx). *** OR *** select by column name. (SEE IN THE UPDATED EXAMPLE) If it is still not working, could you post your code and exception?

Comment: Ah I had to change it to dr(3) as it was the fourth column and it starts with 0.  There are no longer any Runtimes, however the code doesn't help me pre-select the value still.  Using the debugger it breaksdown at the TryCast(...), are you suggesting to extract the ID from the DropDownList?  the department variable has the department name in but the SelectValue will need to select the ID (DataValueField), any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Ah I managed to fix it.  I needed to include the dept_id feild in the initial query, even though I don't output it in the initial DetailView, I use the dept_id to select the value.  I'll update the question to show it.  Thanks so much for your help :D

Comment: I'm glad that you figure out. FYI: next time please ask the question as short as possible, so that you'll get more answers from others. :)